# Managing POST Requests with httpuv package for building a simple API with R

Tags: r, r-rook-package

I am trying to build a simple api using httpuv package.
The documentation says that one could use the same Rook definition. 
While using the Rook package one can simple use:

```
req$POST()
```

I haven't been able to figure out how to manage simple HTTP POST requests and get their body.

Any hints?

Answer (score 6):

I finally got it working. I found the answer lying somewhere in the opencpu package.

Simply read the POST body stream using:

`input <- req[["rook.input"]];`

`postdata <- input$read_lines();`